# Can we disable in-line support in GCC 4.3.3 for linux kernel debugging

Tags: debugging, gcc, linux-kernel, inline, trace32

I am trying to learn about IPSec layer in Linux kernel using Trace 32 ICD. For that I am trying to trace packet flow from user land to Ethernet driver. Problem I'm facing is that Trace32 is not able to display inline functions in stackframe output and therefore are jumps in my flow.

[image]

I am just wondering if :

a) there is a way to disable inline feature for kernel function (or in any program) in GCC.

b) there is a way to add support for inline functions in Trace32 ICD tool.

In case answer for both a & b is no then I would like to know if there exits a workaround to my problem.

**My linux version:** Linux (bts) 3.0.1-rt11-svn9237 #2 PREEMPT RT Fri Dec 21 09:58:42 IST 2012 armv7l GNU/Linux

**My GCC version:** arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.3.3

Comment: Are you ready to rebuild your linux kernel? How yuor version was built?

Comment: Yes I can rebuild my kernel. I have codesourcery toolchain installed on my machine.

Comment: Try to rebuild at `-O2` or lower and with `-fno-inline` option.

Comment: Yeah I got same info from http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html. Will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Here is long dicussion on topic but no conclusion. And they are discussing older GCC version I am note what's situation with new version : http://elinux.org/Extern_Vs_Static_Inline